# Is it possible to manually update the view's details to accessibility service?

Tags: android, accessibility, text-to-speech

Since I'm a new to stack overflow, please forgive for my mistakes.

I've an Horizontal scroll view and few child views inside it.
When I do a fling on the screen to navigate across child views using accessibility focus, it navigates fine (Assume I kept the focus on any child view). I've dismissed that view and reopened it. I'm reusing the view as it is and no accessibility focus I can see on screen. When I fling again to navigate across child views, the focus is missing or jumping some child views.

If I recreate the view or do a small scroll on re open, the focus navigates fine, but not after invalidating the view.

I guess some view status is being maintained with accessibility service, and focus delivered accordingly. Is it possible to update the view's details to accessibility service manually instead of recreating it?

Comment: Android Version, TalkBack Version, Device Version, code snippet?  I think you get the idea, there just is not enough detail here.

Comment: @ChrisCM Android Version: 4.4.2, Talkback Version: 3.6, Device: Moto G. Sorry, I can't share the code snippet. The view implementation is similar to YouTube's Category tab's (like Music, Sports, Videos) shown below the action bar. Thanks :)